# html element converted to image is missing to css styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas, html-to-image

I am currently building a web app that allows users to create or mimic chats on different social media platforms, so far I am done with the html and css but I have been having issues trying to perfectly capture the html element of the chat section so it will look like a screenshot, I have tried using html2canvas and domtoimage libraries but the snapshot/captured html image always omits some vital css styling like background image, border radius and many other stylings

I have tried using libraries like html2canvas, html-to-image, dom-to-image and they all yield the same outcome, i.e making a snapshot that is missing most of the css styling. attached below is an example[image: This is what the screenshot is supposed to look like]
[image: but this is what it looks like when the download button is triggered]

Comment: Could you check  your question, it stops part way through a sentence. Also, for us to be able to help we need to see enough code to do some debugging - at the moment we have no idea how you are applying the background image etc or telling html2canvas what element to convert. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.